# How can i set my image to be on the right?

Tags: html, css, image, css-float

So i have this image which i want to put on the right, but unfortunately it gets stuck in the social media icons when i try to use the pull-right class, im using bootstrap btw.
picture:[image]

and here is how i want it to look like:
[image]

**EDIT:**

Here is a jsfiddle link to the header.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/38z12d3s/)

```
-
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To center the middle logo, apply `justify-content:center; display:flex; width:100%;` and to shift the orange bar to right, apply `position:absolute; top:15px; right:0;`. I have applied **inline stylying**, so just go through the `html`

```css
/*img{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
}*/

.navbar-wrapper {
  z-index: 999;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
  background-color: #1d1d1d;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at center 0px, #31a2a6 -150%, #333240 45%, #333240 85%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at center 0px, #31a2a6 -150%, #333240 45%, #333240 85%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at center 0px, #31a2a6 -150%, #333240 45%, #333240 85%);
  background-image: radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at center 0px, #31a2a6 -150%, #333240 45%, #333240 85%);
  position: relative;
}

.social-top {
  float: left;
  left: 8.333%;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  top: 30px;
  position: absolute;
}

.social-top a:before {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  content: '';
  z-index: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
}

.social-top a {
  padding: 8px 10px 5px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 17px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-image: radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at center 0px, #31a2a6 -150%, #333240 45%, #333240 85%);
  color: #ff8800;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .social-top {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!--HEADER-->
<header>
  <div class="navbar-wrapper">
    <div class="social-top">
      <a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-facebook" style="padding-right: 5px;"></i>
      </a>
      <a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
      </a>
      <a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-youtube"></i>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div style="justify-content:center;display:flex;width:100%;">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="https://image.prntscr.com/image/MFOIvVb5TRO8-AgQGFTJAw.png" style="padding: 15px;" alt="Hiraeth logo">
    </div>
    
    <div style="position:absolute;top:0;right:0;">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="https://image.prntscr.com/image/3knsxcoiQ2_pFpe_PcG-sQ.png" alt="Hiraeth logo">
    </div>
  </div>

</header>
<!--END HEADER-->
```

Comment: It doesnt work, nothing happens, the height just gets bigger and the image stays in the same place.

Comment: What problem you face now? Have you seen the snippet? have you applied `pull-right ` class in the `img` tag

Comment: Umm, you are pulling the logo to the right which should be in the middle. there is another picture which should be pulled to the right, but it gets stuck at the social media icons. Please see the jsfiddle on the post.

Comment: I have just seen your fiddle, you have applied `position:absolute` in the orange bar, so remove that as no need of absolute positioning there, it will work.

Comment: Yes it does work indeed, but now how i want it to work. The logo wont be centered and it will be pushed away from the middle.
Picture:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0LCx.png

Comment: Whoa, that is really not looking cool. The orange bar's height should fit the whole wrapper and the logo is really stretched. **EDIT:**
Alright it works, but now the wrapper's background doesnt appear.
Picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQx9M.png

Comment: for me images are very big, so I have applied some styling like `width` and `height`, have you seen the css for `img` tag? you can change that

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the `pull-right` class and it gets stuck there that means that the parent div is located there and does not have the width of the nav-bar. I suggest that you place the picture in a div that has the width of the whole nav-bar and then apply the `pull-right` class. Use dev-tools on chrome to easily locate in which div exactly to put the img. I hope this helps!

Sorry for not posting this as a comment, I still do not have 50 rep.

EDIT: here is a working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/38z12d3s/1/) with the fix, for any other people facing a similar problem!

Comment: If you provide me with a JS Fiddle of your problem, I can take a look and fix it.

Comment: I am sorry but I wont be able to help you in that case. I would suggest you then to make a "wrapper" around you image that has the width of the whole navbar and then apply text-align: right; style. Or you can do the float: left; style on the <img> tag. Hope this helps you out!

Comment: Ok i added a jsfiddle link, check it out please.

Comment: @Detoxical here you go buddy [JSFIDDLE edit](https://jsfiddle.net/38z12d3s/1/) Hope this helps you out!

Comment: Thank you very much!
There is another jsfiddle link with less css, only with the needed ones, could you do the changes on that one too pleasE? EDIT: Alright, nevermind i see the changes, thanks again!

Comment: @Detoxical if this helped you out may I please ask you for a favor and upvote my answer and comments just so I can help other people and be able to comment under other answers! (i am still under 50rep) Thank you!

Comment: Actually it doesnt work. I mean it works but not how i'd like it to work. The logo wont be centered and if i want to apply absolute position on the orange picture which should be at the right it just disappears.